# Redirect to another page after submitting a form and retrieve value from the input field

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new in Django but know some stuff and still need your help.

I want when a user submits a button after putting info in the search area to redirect to another page and accept data for future use.

What I did so far:

in **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
```

**in forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Child

class ChildlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('name',)
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def home(request):
    form = ChildForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChildForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=True)
        else:
            return 'main/test.html'
        return render(request,'main/index2.html',{'name':data.name})
    return render(request,'main/index.html',{'form':form})
```

`'test.html'` is where the form is required to be filled by user. I want after the inform submitted the data is saved and then redirected to garden.html file.

the **test.html** file

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text">
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
```

the form is search ready template posted by bootstrap.

Could you please help to link successfully the files and get the data (name) to further use in garden.html?

In **index2.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{% block content %}
  {{b}}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def home(request):
    form = ChildForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ChildForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=True)
            name=data.name
            symbols = [name]
            yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(symbols)
            new_data = pd.DataFrame()
            for s in symbols :
            new_data[s] = wb.DataReader(s, data_source ='yahoo', start = '2014-1-1')['Adj Close']

            a = new_data[s]
            b = a[-1]
            context={
            'name':name,
            'b':b
            }
        else:
            form = ChildForm()
            return render(request,'test.html',{'form':form})
        return render(request,'garden.html',context)
    return render(request,'test.html',{'form':form})
```

besides there is a typo in your code

```
class ChildlForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Comment: I ran this code and worked fine. make sure the indentations are at correct level
Here is a working sample
https://repl.it/repls/InfamousClientsideTranslations

Comment: Hey i have my last question would appreciate to get your insight or any help. I made the changes you said as you can see in  view.py  file under the function i am giving command to return the input as ticker sign from yahoo finance and return from yahoo finance stock price.  I put name in brackets and identified as variable: symbols=[name]. It should return input variable in 'AAPL' and extract data and display value b in index2 file. However it does not show anything. Can you please explain what is the problem?

Comment: Is the probelm in identation or i need to define a new function? I do not want to define as i want it to be global variables so i can use for other commands. What do you think?

Comment: The view will terminate when it reaches a return statement. so the lines including 
symbols = [name] and below are unreachable logic. you will need to include them before the return statement and pass the desired values in the context

Comment: When i put them before def home() the terminal says that name is not defined . Do i understand  you correctly or i am wrong?please see the views.py above. Please explain what i need to do to make it work as i want to keep them global and be used with other functions

Comment: I tried to put to various position but the treminal says that name is not defined when i put it before  def home() function. Could you please show an example how it show be located. this is my last question ))))

Comment: assuming that "b" is the value you want to pass to the next page,  I have edited my answer. the function starts at def home() so anything you write above the function will not work and won't be reachable

Comment: Yeah thank you i understood the logic. My only question is that i should put all variables that i want to pass to the next page in the context?Is there more efficient way to put all available variables as i have lot of variables to pass to the next page?

Comment: you have to pass the values to HTML pages via context. if it is a datatype like list, you don't have to pass every single values individually. you only have to pass the list in context and can access them or iterate over them in the html templates

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Hey. I have a question. How can i change the input to search bar? Should i use inside serach code {{form}} or it differs from form format? Could you please give some guidance where to look for?